# Need help with a C26495 warning and E0513 error in a C++ SFML class

Tags: c++, animation, sfml, visual-studio

I'm currently learning to program a game with the SFML library.I dugged up a bunch of SFML tutorials on Youtube and found a really good one by 'Suraj Sharma':

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2i39AOpDSlO1Mrn1jQ8Xkg

I'm now making an animation class following his tutorial. Here's the video I'm watching:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pq9OuBHJiVM&list=PL6xSOsbVA1ebkU66okpi-KViAO8_9DJKg&index=27

> A C26495 warning:Variable 'AnimCmp::Timer' is uninitialized.Always initialize a member variable(type.6).
>   Blockquote

and a

> E0513 error:a value of type "AnimCmp::Anim*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "AnimCmp::Anim*"

appears right when I was watching the first 8 minutes of the video. Here's my code, compiled in Visual Studio 2019 community (Take notes that all declared classes, functions and variables are an abbreviated version of the video):

AnimCmp.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef ANIM_CMP_H
#define ANIM_CMP_H
//i've put every required headers in a precompiled one
#include "pch.h"

class AnimCmp
{
private:
    class Anim {
    public:
        //Vars
        sf::Sprite& Spr;
        sf::Texture& TexSheet;
        sf::IntRect StartRct;
        sf::IntRect CurrRect;
        sf::IntRect EndRct;

        float Timer;
        float AnimTimer;
        int w;
        int h;
        //C26495 at Anim's constuctor
        Anim(sf::Sprite& Spr, sf::Texture& TexSheet, float AnimTimer, int stx, int sty, int frx, int fry, int w, int h)
            :Spr(Spr), TexSheet(TexSheet),AnimTimer(AnimTimer),w(w),h(h){
            this->w = w;
            this->h = h;
            this->StartRct = sf::IntRect(stx * w, sty * h, w, h);
            this->CurrRect = this->StartRct;
            this->EndRct = sf::IntRect(frx * w, fry * h, w, h);

            this->Spr.setTexture(this->TexSheet, true);
            this->Spr.setTextureRect(this->StartRct);
        }
        //virtual~Anim();
        //Functions
        //void Pause();
        void Reset() {
            this->Timer = 0.f;
            this->CurrRect = this->StartRct;
        }

        void Play(const float& dt) {
            //Update Timer
            this->Timer = 10.f*dt;
            if (this->Timer >= this->AnimTimer) {
                //Reset Timer
                this->Timer = 0.f;
                //Animate
                if (this->CurrRect != this->EndRct) {
                    this->CurrRect.left += this->w;
                }
                else {//Reset
                    this->CurrRect.left = this->StartRct.left;
                }
                this->Spr.setTextureRect(this->CurrRect);
            }
        }
    };

    sf::Sprite& Spr;
    sf::Texture& TexSheet;
    std::map<std::string, Anim*> Anims;
public:
    AnimCmp(sf::Sprite& Spr,sf::Texture& TexSheet);
    virtual~AnimCmp();
    //Functions
    void AddAnim(const std::string key, sf::Sprite& Spr, sf::Texture& TexSheet,
        float AnimTimer, int stx, int sty, int frx, int fry, int w, int h);

    void Start(const std::string Anim);
    void Pause(const std::string Anim);
    void Reset(const std::string Anim);
    void Play(const std::string key, const float& dt);
};
#endif // !ANIM_CMP_H
```

AnimCmp.cpp:

```
#include "AnimCmp.h"

AnimCmp::AnimCmp(sf::Sprite& Spr, sf::Texture& TexSheet)
    :Spr(Spr),TexSheet(TexSheet)
{
}

AnimCmp::~AnimCmp()
{
    for (auto& i : this->Anims) {
        delete i.second;
    }
}

void AnimCmp::AddAnim(const std::string key, sf::Sprite& Spr, sf::Texture& TexSheet,float AnimTimer, int stx, int sty,
 int frx, int fry, int w, int h)
{
    this->Anims[key] = new Anim(this->Spr, this->TexSheet, AnimTimer, stx, sty, frx, fry, w, h);//E0513
}
//Functions
void AnimCmp::Start(const std::string Anim)
{
}

void AnimCmp::Pause(const std::string Anim)
{
}

void AnimCmp::Reset(const std::string Anim)
{
}

void AnimCmp::Play(const std::string key, const float& dt)
{
    this->Anims[key]->Play(dt);
}
```

The thing is the game still runs even when an error is showing. I'm just not sure how it'll affect the game.

Answer (score 1):

> A C26495 warning:Variable 'AnimCmp::Timer' is uninitialized.Always initialize a member variable(type.6).

As it says, the compiler tells you that you have a class variable that is not initialized.

It will most likely look at the variable declaration

```
class AnimCmp
{
private:
    class Anim {
    public:
        //Vars
        float Timer;
```

...in the constructor initialization list...

```
            :Spr(Spr), TexSheet(TexSheet),AnimTimer(AnimTimer),w(w),h(h){
```

...or in the constructor body...

```
        {
            this->w = w;
            this->h = h;
            this->StartRct = sf::IntRect(stx * w, sty * h, w, h);
            this->CurrRect = this->StartRct;
            this->EndRct = sf::IntRect(frx * w, fry * h, w, h);

            this->Spr.setTexture(this->TexSheet, true);
            this->Spr.setTextureRect(this->StartRct);
        }
```

to find a place where you actually assign a value to the variable.

In no case here there is such a thing.

So you have the choice, either:

at the variable declaration

```
class AnimCmp
{
private:
    class Anim {
    public:
        //Vars
        float Timer {};
```

...in the constructor initialization list...

```
            :Spr(Spr), TexSheet(TexSheet),AnimTimer(AnimTimer),w(w),h(h),Timer(0.0f){
```

...or in the constructor body...

```
        {
            this->Timer = 0.0f;
            this->w = w;
            this->h = h;
            this->StartRct = sf::IntRect(stx * w, sty * h, w, h);
            this->CurrRect = this->StartRct;
            this->EndRct = sf::IntRect(frx * w, fry * h, w, h);

            this->Spr.setTexture(this->TexSheet, true);
            this->Spr.setTextureRect(this->StartRct);
        }
```

An uninitialized variable will always behave the same in debug mode because the compiler is happy to set a default value for you, but all hell can break loose in release. It's possible that your code is unaffected by such a thing, but the compiler does not know that. Better to initialize it for the sake of remove potential issues.

---

As for your other issue, I'm not exactly certain why it is occurring. Maybe you do not show everything that has to be shown for us to give you a definitive answer.

Shooting in the dark, and following a google search, you might have declared some parts of the map (or the function) as being `const`, or maybe the compiler [thinks your c++ code is actually c code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23283712).

Comment: Thanks for the help,so far the code still works fine and i haven't found anything wrong in debug mode.I'll take your suggestions and take a look.